# Optimize image conversion

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am trying to optimize some image conversion code to boost the framerate in my system. I now copy from a source pixel by pixel, but that is not really efficient.

I have a pointer to a uint8_t array, which formerly was a pointer to a char array. Either of the two should be filled in the data field of a sensor_msgs::Image message.

I am not an expert, please enlighten me with the efficient approach here! :)

```
      uint8_t *uint8_pointer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>( (unsigned char*) grayscale_channel[0].L() );

      int height = atoi(height_pointer.ToString().Text());
      int width  = atoi(width_pointer.ToString().Text());

      sensor_msgs::Image output_image;

      output_image.header.stamp     = timestamp.data;
      output_image.height           = height;
      output_image.width            = width;
      output_image.encoding         = "mono8";
      output_image.is_bigendian     = false;
      output_image.step             = 1 * width;

      for(int i=0; i<(width*height);i++)
      {
           output_image.data.push_back(uint8_pointer[i]);
      }

      return output_image;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198175/optimize-image-conversion/) by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2014-11-24**:
I tried simply pushing back the dereferenced pointer, however that throws an error during runtime.

```
output_image.data.push_back( *uint8_pointer );
```

The error:

```
 Error loading image: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not match calculated image size in Imag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The for() loop can be replaced by:

```
output_image.data.resize(width*height); // Allocate memory
memcpy(output_image.data.data(), uint8_pointer, width*height); // Efficient copy
```

Instead of running individual nodes, running several nodelets in a single process can also speed up message transmission. http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2014-11-25**:
That works!

I will do some reading on memory allocation and memcopy. Also thanks for the reference to the nodelet, that might also be very valuable to speed things up. :)